# Python Tkinter Checkbutton alignment to other widgets

Tags: python, tkinter, widget

So i have some tkinter checkboxes in a frame widget, which should be aligned to each other. I thought with grid and then using sticky='w' should align them to most east as possible of the column. So to say, to have the checkbox-squares aligned. Instead this happens (the relief is just to see the boundaries of the checkbutton widgets):

[Image of GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ehELT.jpg)

The documentation of the widget - in my opinion - does not provide a function to set this. With the sticky of grid i am not sure whether it should even be the function. Actually the relief shows its sticky in that column...

Here is my code example:

```
    def init_checkboxes(self):
    """
    Creates all checkboxes for this particular frame subclass.
    """
    self.bvar_cbx_showplots = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
    self.cbx_showplots = tk.Checkbutton(self.lblframe, width=20,
                                        text='Show Plots after run',
                                        variable=self.bvar_cbx_showplots,
                                        relief='groove')
    self.cbx_showplots.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W')
    self.bvar_cbx_saveres = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
    self.cbx_saveres = tk.Checkbutton(self.lblframe, width=20,
                                      text='Save simulation results',
                                      variable=self.bvar_cbx_saveres,
                                      relief='groove')
    self.cbx_saveres.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W')
```

edit: [Second attempt from Reblochon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Gb8.jpg)

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Comment: thanks, i will consider this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`anchor`](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111212955/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/checkbutton.htm#Tkinter.Checkbutton.config-method).

> anchor=
> Controls where in the button the text (or image) should be located. Use one of **N**, **NE**, **E**, **SE**, **S**, **SW**, **W**, **NW**, or **CENTER.** Default is **CENTER**. If you change this, it is probably a good idea to add some padding as well, using the **padx** and/or **pady** options. (anchor/Anchor)

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

bvar_cbx_showplots = tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
cbx_showplots = tk.Checkbutton(root, width=20,
                               text='Show Plots after run',
                               variable=bvar_cbx_showplots,
                               relief='groove', anchor='w')
cbx_showplots.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='W')

bvar_cbx_saveres = tk.BooleanVar(value=True)
cbx_saveres = tk.Checkbutton(root, width=20,
                             text='Save simulation results',
                             variable=bvar_cbx_saveres,
                             relief='groove', anchor='w')
cbx_saveres.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='W')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works just amazing, thanks! Acutally i had a bad documentation site open, where anchor wasn't mentioned... [See this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_checkbutton.htm). Sorry, but thanks!

Comment: I usually use the effbot page I linked or the [New Mexico Tech](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) pages. those are both great resources.